# Remove svn:externals property from a folder

Tags: svn, branch, externals

I have a branch of the trunk. I need to re-set the properties of the externals in the branch to a different point.
My idea was to remove them all and re-set them with propset.
When I type `svn propdel svn:externals http://path-to-branch/externals`

I get

> svn: E200009: Targets must be working copy paths

Whats the problem with my command?

Comment: Ok, i've tried: 
svn propset --revprop -r HEAD svn:externals "http://abc /abc" http://svn-server-path-to-branch/Externals
svn: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
svn: E175008: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
svn: E175002: Error setting property 'externals': Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 1) with output: Changing revision properties other than svn:log is prohibited

Not sure what that means...

Comment: "Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hoot" - Assuming that's a typo and you meant hook, it means there's a custom pre-rev hook thats preventing you from making the change. You'll need to contact your repository's administrator.

Answer (score 13):

Your command is operating on the repository URL, not a working copy.  Check out a working copy first:

```
svn co http://path-to-branch path/to/workingcopy
```

Then modify the property in your working copy:

```
svn propdel svn:externals path/to/workingcopy
```

Commit the change, and you should be all set.  I would be remiss not to point out that it is not actually necessary to delete them first, propedit will overwrite whatever the property was beforehand.

Comment: I've tried the following to over write some properties, but i'm not sure of the syntax:

Comment: I've tried the following to over write some properties, but i'm not sure of the syntax: svn propset svn:externals --revprop -r HEAD "http://abc /abc" "http://target-to-svn-branch/externals" but it says that at least one propery change failed and "Error setting property 'externals': Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hoot... Changing revision properties other than svn:log is prohibited"

Comment: @Gui - externals is versioned property of PATH, not unversioned of revision

Comment: "Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hoot" - Assuming that's a typo and you meant hook, it means there's a custom pre-rev hook thats preventing you from making the change.  You'll need to contact your repository's administrator.